# Extract data from a website with simplehtmldom

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to **extract some data from HTML DIV using Simple HTML Dom** but it's not working right.

When I try to extract data from links/imgs it works fine but I have only a problem with `DIV`s.

HTML code:

```
<div class="price-container">
 <div class="price-calc-container" id="attributes-calc-price">
    <div class="current-price-container">
       7,99 EUR
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to extarct the number inside this div

```
$html = file_get_html("https://www.test.de/");

$preise = $html->find('div.current-price-container');

print_r($preise);
```

Sometime I will get an empty array sometimes nothing.

Comment: What you mean buy sometimes. Are you trying for scrapping

Comment: I mean sometime i will get and empty array on screen sometimes nothing.      yeah i want to scrape the price.

Comment: try `$preise = $html->find('current-price-container');` and tell me is it working or does it generate any errors

Comment: i didnt get any errors but still an empty Array
(
)

Comment: can you add the complete html code in a div

Comment: Just add a `id ` into price div then tell me is it working

Comment: when i used it with id   PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1071648768 bytes)

Comment: can you tell me the url you try to scrap. So that I can try

Comment: the url is already there  [link](https://www.led-centrum.de/LED-Leuchtmittel/led-strahler/LED-Strahler-GU10/4058075160071.html)

Comment: is Damien's answer working??????

Comment: i think the problem is with the allowed memory size i will try to change it and see

Comment: ok tell me if its not working so that I can try

Comment: I tried your code (as is, except the typo with missing `$` in `$html =...`) and it works as expected. What's the exact problem here?

Comment: the problem that im using the same code as above but getting an empty array

Comment: @M.Aldein waite trying to test

Answer (score 0):

You have to start iterating over the find() result or use the last parameter to specify an index

```
$html = file_get_html("https://www.led-centrum.de/LED-Leuchtmittel/led-strahler/LED-Strahler-GU10/4058075160071.html");
$preise = $html->find('div.current-price-container', 0);
print_r($preise);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Jquery command like this
Try this

```
<div class="price-container">
 <div class="price-calc-container" id="attributes-calc-price">
 <div class="current-price-container">
    7,99 EUR
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var x = $('.current-price-container').text();
console.log(x);
</script>
```

Comment: he wants to do it server side

Comment: Okay but we can achieve it using jquery also then we can store it in php using cookies